# How to use dynamic variable in media query?

Tags: css, sass

I have a few variables as the following, I want to use it in a media query, I trying to use  #{viewport-$type} but no lucky, sass compiler would not compile my syntax and say "unclosed parenthesis in media query expression". So, how should I do that? can anyone helpe? thanks.

```
$viewport-large: "max-width: 1441px";
$viewport-midium: "max-width: 1281px";
$viewport-small: "max-width: 1025px";

$type: midium;

@media (#{viewport-$type}) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can reference variables dynamically within media query in Sass. However for things like this you can use [Sass maps](http://www.sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#maps) along with the [`map-get` function](http://www.sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#map_get-instance_method).

```css
$viewport:(
  large: "max-width: 1441px",
  medium: "max-width: 1281px",
  small: "max-width: 1025px");

$type: medium;

@media (map-get($viewport, $type)) { /* map-get - param 1 is the map, param 2 is the key */
  #demo {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Here is the [reference thread from Sass GitHub page](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/132#issuecomment-46554767).